# Como passar uma variavel para dentro de um callback em php com Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Estou tentando fazer um método um pouco abstrato que executara uma query do yii2 dependendo do atributo passado meu código está:

```
public static function getModelosQuePodemTer($atributo) {
    self::$helper = $atributo;
    return self::find()
                ->joinWith(['modelo' => function($query) {
                        $query->andWhere([self::$helper => 1]);
                    }])
                ->all();
```

Se não me engano não posso passar mais um atributo na função que esta sendo chamada, e creio que minha solução é uma gambiarra

gostaria de saber se existe outra forma de fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `use` para acessar a váriavel `$atributo` dentro do escopo da função.

```
public static function getModelosQuePodemTer($atributo) {

    return self::find()
                ->joinWith(['modelo' => function($query)use($atributo) {
                        $query->andWhere([$atributo=> 1]);
                    }])
                ->all();
```

Comment: Obrigado :) funcionou certinho

Comment: Boaa! por nada =]